# foreach loop not generating the right html table

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

I'm trying to get this output from returned data fetched from mysql:

```
 <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th></th><th><img src='img1.jpg'></th><th><img src='img2.jpg'></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='5'>Features</td>
          <td>LCD</td><td>Yes</td><td>No</td>
          <td>Auto Pilot</td><td>No</td><td>No</td>
          <td>Fast Generation</td><td>Yes</td><td>No</td>
          <td>Dual Cores</td><td>No</td><td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

But I have trouble getting the following code to achieve that output with one foreach loop. It uses `in_array` to check whether each value from $featured_tests exists in the returned data.

```
  $featured_tests = array("LCD","Auto Pilot","Fast Generation","Dual Cores");
  $table_head ="<table><thead><tr><th></th>";
  $table_colspan1 = "</tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan='5'>Features</td></tr>";
  $table_end ="</tr></tbody></table>";

    foreach($rows as $row) 
    {
      $special_features = explode(",",$row->special_features);
      $header_image .= "<th><img src='".$row->image_url."'></th>";
      foreach($featured_tests as $featured_test)
      {
        $featured .= "<tr><td>".$featured_test."</td>";

        if(in_array($featured_test,$special_features))
        {
          $featured .= "<td>Yes</td>";
        }
        else
        {
          $featured .= "<td>No</td>";
        }    
      }
   }


 $table_html = $table_head.$header_image.$table_colspan1.$featured.$table_end;
```

But the result I'm getting is a mess. Each value in `$featured_tests` is iterating over and over again for each product and thus results in a very long table. Can anyone help me correct my code to get the ideal output?

Here's the result:

```
 <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th></th><th><img src='img1.jpg'></th><th><img src='img2.jpg'></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='5'>Features</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>LCD</td><td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Auto Pilot</td>No<td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fast Generation</td><td>Yes</td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>         
          <td>Dual Cores</td>No<td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>LCD</td><td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Auto Pilot</td>No<td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fast Generation</td><td>No</td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>         
          <td>Dual Cores</td>Yes<td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: you're opening a `<tr>` for every item iterated in your `foreach()`, but you only close ONCE `</tr>` OUTSIDE of the loop. I can't see how your example output corresponds to the code.

Comment: The posted result is final one or you have posted the part of the result??? as you mentioned  its generating a very long table.

Comment: I would like to see the what `$rows` looks like

Comment: Kender, the `$row->special_features` is a string with comma seperators something like `Auto Pilot,Red,Dual Cores,Grey`, then I use inarray to check whether each of the array elements from `$featured_tests` exists in the `$row->special_features`.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new rows `<tr>` inside on most deep foreach...

take this example to make what you want:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($large_array as $less_array): ?>
            <tr>
            <?php foreach($less_array as $row): ?>
                <!-- <td> contents etc</td>-->
            <?php endforeach?>
            </tr>
       <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```